# Android video thumbnail is null

Tags: android, bitmap, thumbnails, video-thumbnails

So basically what I'm trying to achieve is that the user can choose to select an existing video or take a new one, but my bitmap has always a null value.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK || requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedVideo = data.getData();
        addVideoToTable(ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(selectedVideo.getPath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND));
    }
}

public void addVideoToTable(Bitmap video) {
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.videoTable);
    if (videoCount == 0 || videoCount % 3 == 0) {
        tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL));
        tl.addView(tr);
    }
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setImageBitmap(video);
    iv.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 10);
    iv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 300, 1f));
    tr.addView(iv);
    videoCount++;
}
```

Comment: basically what exactly you want to do ? work on video thumbnail or work on capture or select video ?

Comment: Well I need to have the video thumbnail, the capture/select video works fine.

Comment: means, want to work over video thumbnail ?

Comment: Yes, I give the user the option to select a video or create a new one(This works). From there I want to create a video thumbnail, once it's created I want to show it ofcourse.

Comment: refer this one, useful to create thumbnail for image and video both [link](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
public String getPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

    //Source not from device capture or selection
    if (cursor == null) { 
        return uri.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        if ( idx == -1 ) {
            return uri.getPath();
    }

    String path =  cursor.getString(idx);
    cursor.close();
    return path;
}
```

This should work for when you select a local video that is either capture, or stored on a user's device. The reason it isn't working for you is that you are getting just the raw path, rather than the path in the media store that the method ThumbnailUtils uses.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, good luck with the rest of your project :)